# Turning off Webalizer and/or AW Stats

Tags: apache, server, mysql, cpanel, awstats

On our dedicated server, we have AW Stats and Webalizer both running.

I see I can turn them off in WHM.

We use Google Analytics, but also AW Stats sometimes.  We never use Webzlier.  My question is:  Does disabling Webalizer and/or AW Stats reduce any load on the server, apache or mysql?  Is there a benefit to turning it off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your server is configured, but in general yes if you don't use it I would turn it off and it will save on server resources. Webalizer and Awstats do very similar things, they analyze your server's access log and turn it into readable data about your visitors. Depending on your traffic this can be relatively intensive, if you are running Awstats and Webalizer you are basically analyzing the same log twice for no reason. Short answer - yes disable it.

Answer (score 0):

There will definitely be a benefit to turning it off. Webalizer will read all of the server's logs and write a bunch of summary files. So your hard disk will see lower resource usage. In addition, if there's a fair amount of traffic to the site(s), the process could consume a significant portion of your available memory.